TypeScript Error: Property 'userId' does not exist on type 'Session & Partial<SessionData>'
I'm encountering a TypeScript compilation error related to session management in my Node.js application. Here is the error message I receive:
D:\Web Dev\RAHI\Backend\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:859
    return new TSError(diagnosticText, diagnosticCodes, diagnostics);
           ^
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/controllers/user.controller.ts:134:19 - error TS2339: Property 'userId' does not exist on type 'Session & Partial<SessionData>'.

134       req.session.userId = user.id; // Save userId in session
                      ~~~~~~
src/controllers/user.controller.ts:135:31 - error TS2339: Property 'userId' does not exist on type 'Session & Partial<SessionData>'.

135       console.log(req.session.userId); // This should now work
                                  ~~~~~~

    at createTSError (D:\Web Dev\RAHI\Backend\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:859:12)
    at reportTSError (D:\Web Dev\RAHI\Backend\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:863:19)
    at getOutput (D:\Web Dev\RAHI\Backend\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:1077:36)
    at Object.compile (D:\Web Dev\RAHI\Backend\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:1433:41)
    at Module.m._compile (D:\Web Dev\RAHI\Backend\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:1617:30)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (D:\Web Dev\RAHI\Backend\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:1621:12)      
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1235:19) {
  diagnosticCodes: [ 2339, 2339 ]
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Related Files:
1. src/controllers/user.controller.ts:
const loginUser = asyncHandler(async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    const { email, mobileNo, password }: LoginRequestBody = req.body;
    console.log(req.body)
    if (!(email || mobileNo)) {
        throw new ApiError(400, 'Email or mobile number is required');
    }

    const user = await User.findOne({
        where: {
            [Op.or]: [
                { email },
                { mobileNo }
            ]
        }
    });

    if (!user) {
        throw new ApiError(404, "User doesn't exist with the given email or mobile number");
    }

    const isPasswordValid = await user.comparePassword(password);

    if (!isPasswordValid) {
        throw new ApiError(401, 'Invalid user credentials!');
    }

    const { accessToken, refreshToken } = await generateAccessRefreshToken(user.id);

    if (req.session) {
        req.session.userId = user.id; // Save userId in session
        console.log(req.session.userId); // This should now work
    }

    const loggedInUser = await User.findByPk(user.id);
    if (!loggedInUser) {
        throw new ApiError(500, 'Failed to retrieve user information');
    }

    const userResponse = loggedInUser.get({ plain: true }) as any;
    delete userResponse.password;
    delete userResponse.refreshToken;

    const options = {
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: true,
    };

    return res
        .status(200)
        .cookie('accessToken', accessToken, options)
        .cookie('refreshToken', refreshToken, options)
        .json(
            new ApiResponse(
                200,
                {
                    user: userResponse,
                    refreshToken,
                },
                'User logged in successfully'
            )
        );
});

2. types/session.d.ts:
import 'express-session';

declare module 'express-session' {
    interface SessionData {
        userId: any; // Or change the type based on your user ID format
    }
}

3. app.ts:
import express, { Express } from "express";
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
import cors from 'cors';
import session from 'express-session';
import Sequelize from './db/index';
import sessionStore from 'connect-session-sequelize';

const app: Express = express();

const SequelizeStore = sessionStore(session.Store);

export const store = new SequelizeStore({
    db: Sequelize,
});

app.use(
    cors({
        origin: process.env.CORS_ORIGIN,
        credentials: true,  // Ensures cookies are sent with requests
    })
);

app.use(express.json({ limit: '16kb' }));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true, limit: '16kb' }));
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET || "",
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: store,
    cookie: {
        maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // 30 days
        secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
    }
}));

import userRoutes from '@routes/user.route'

app.use('/api/v1/users', userRoutes);
export { app };

4. tsconfig.json:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "NodeNext",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["node_modules/*"],
      "@models/*": ["models/*"],
      "@controllers/*": ["controllers/*"],
      "@utils/*": ["utils/*"],
      "@db/*": ["db/*"],
      "@middlewares/*":["middlewares/*"],
      "@routes/*":["routes/*"],
      "@customTypes/*": ["customTypes/*"],
      "@src/*":["D:/Web Dev/RAHI/Backend/src/*"]
    },
    "typeRoots": [ "./node_modules/@types","src/types"]
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*", "src/types"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules/*", "dist"]
}


Issue:
I am getting TypeScript errors indicating that the property userId does not exist on type Session & Partial<SessionData>. I have defined the userId property in types/session.d.ts, but it doesn't seem to be recognized.
Questions:

Why is TypeScript not recognizing the userId property in the session object?
What steps can I take to resolve this issue and ensure TypeScript acknowledges the custom session property?


Could you provide your ts config file?

@hoangdv pls check added the tsconfig

It seems ts-node issue, you can try to run your code by ts-node --files ... (adding --files option). Or define "files": ["src/types/session.d.ts"] in your ts config file.

@hoangdv "dev": "nodemon --exec \"ts-node --files -r tsconfig-paths/register\" src/index.ts", this solved the issue but can you explain what the issue was?
